# Autofac Keyed/Named methods do not provide overload with service mapping func

Tags: c#, autofac

The `As` method provides an overload with a `Func<Type, Type> serviceMapping` parameter, but the `Keyed` and `Named` methods do not. They only provide `Func<Type, object> serviceKeyMapping` and `Func<Type, string> serviceNameMapping` parameters, respectively.

However, I want to register a set of types with `RegisterAssemblyTypes` using the same key for all of the types, but using a different interface determined by the type itself. I was expecting to find a method overload such as `Keyed(object serviceKey, Func<Type, Type> serviceMapping)` or `Keyed(Func<Type, object> serviceKeyMapping, Func<Type, Type> serviceMapping)`.

Is this an oversight in the API design? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the API doesn't have such feature. You could however use the `As(Func<Type, Service> serviceMapping)` overload with a `KeyedService` object.

For example

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Parent).Assembly)
        .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<ICommon>())
        .As(t => new KeyedService(keyObject, t.GetType().GetInterfaces()[0]));
```

`KeyedService` is in `Autofac.Core` namespace. There is no `NamedService` object but you can use a `KeyedService` with a `string`

Comment: I've been using Autofac for years and never discovered the `KeyedService` class. Wish they would add that to the [docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).